# TYPO3 11 RecordList, edit query with filters

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 11.
I created a custom entity "bando".
In back-end I use the recordlist module to show all "bando" entities.

[image]

It is possible to add a search filter? and can I edit the query?
TCA config can only set searchFields

I tried some hooks but are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called querybuilder which would help you achieve this.https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/querybuilder Please have a look into this extension.

[image]

Comment: It works with TYPO3 10

Comment: Yes, it works with TYPO3 10.4 @MarioProject

Comment: I  have TYPO3 11.

Comment: @MarioProject Siva,  They does have a WIP for TYPO3 v11 compatibility. I've been looking forward to this as well. Might come in handy. https://github.com/TYPO3GmbH/querybuilder/pull/13

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in full search in the TYPO3 core, that can do both a raw search and an advanced query, that can be configured based on the TCA of the table you want to search in:

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-lowlevel/main/en-us/BackendModules/DbCheck/FullSearch.html

Comment: I don't thin that a simple user wants to write a query to view some results...

Comment: Your original question was: "and can I edit the query?" - The answer is: Yes, you can!

IIRC you can even store those queries as actions that can then be clicked by simple users to just get the result without having to create the query.

https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/sys_action